# Xcode not showing simulators after downgrading from 10.2 to 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode

Simulator list is empty - typical attempts at restarting Xcode, restarting computer, modifying schemes, do not work. Downloading simulators had no effect.

Comment: Create a new project with Single View Application, it check it it show list of simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build Settings -> IOS Deployment Target -> Choose a deployment target if it is grayed out.

As soon as the deployment target is chosen, the simulators will appear. The deployment target determines your app's capability of running on a certain version, evidently it is a dependency to the simulator.

Comment: Please add a brief explanation of how and why this works for everyone's benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps:

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools -> Select Xcode 10.1
```

Or

```
Window -> Devices & Simulators -> Add Simulator
```